# unable to connect to remote device in python

Tags: python, wireshark, smb

I am trying to connect to my local `NAS` using `SMBConnection`

Below is the complete code

```
from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection

def connector():

    conn  =SMBConnection('admin','********',remote_name='MyCloudEX2Ultra',my_name='DESKTOP-I7')
    ret =conn.connect('192.168.0.102')
    print("return val " + str(ret))
    res = conn.listPath(service_name= 'smbclient' ,path= '/Public2')

    for i in res:
        print (i)
    return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("In main module")
    ret = connector()
```

I see that the access didn't go through , on further checking I see on wireshark an error code `STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME`. I didn't see any reference for this issue , has any one seen similar error and figured out a way to get the access through , below is wireshark output

[image]

Edit 1 
After removing Try catch block, i see the below error

OperationFailure: Failed to list Public2 on smbclient: Unable to connect to shared device
==================== SMB Message 0 ====================

### SMB Header:

Command: 0x03 (SMB2_COM_TREE_CONNECT) 
Status: 0x00000000 
Flags: 0x00 
PID: 14404 
MID: 3 
TID: 0 
Data: 62 bytes 
b'09000000480036005c005c004d00590043004c004f005500440045005800320055004c005400520041005c0073006d00620063006c00690065006e007400'

### SMB Data Packet (hex):

b'fe534d42400000000000000003000000000000000000000003000000000000004438000000000000a9a30c72000000000000000000000000000000000000000009000000480036005c005c004d00590043004c004f005500440045005800320055004c005400520041005c0073006d00620063006c00690065006e007400'
==================== SMB Message 1 ====================

### SMB Header:

Command: 0x03 (SMB2_COM_TREE_CONNECT) 
Status: 0xC00000CC 
Flags: 0x01 
PID: 14404 
MID: 3 
TID: 0 
Data: 9 bytes 
b'090000000000000000'

### SMB Data Packet (hex):

b'fe534d4240000000cc0000c003000100010000000000000003000000000000004438000000000000a9a30c720000000000000000000000000000000000000000090000000000000000'

Comment: Please avoid uploading pictures of code, and simply copy-pasting it in using the appropriate formatting

Comment: First thing to do: remove the whole `try` / `except` / `finally` structure to see the real error message. Like this you get on `something went wrong` and you will return without running the code below.

Comment: `//server/service` name apparently did not get anything it could connect to and I have to say `//MyCloudEX2Ultra//` looks fairly odd. Are you sure about `service_name='/'`? You should be also able to use `smbclient` to just try connecting from command line and see how that fares.